# Why does adblock block incomes for ads?

Tags: ads, adblock

Why doesn't adblock block incomes for ads? Is it because the requests to the advertiser are blocked? Is it because the is some kind of adblock detector in ads? Wouldn't it be possible to make a white cover or change the opacity?

Note: I am seeking a technical explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It blocks most of the income. Most ads only gain money for every visitor click, not ad views.  The hoster of the ad only gains money when his ads are clicked on, since adblock removes these ads, there is nowhere for users to click. and no reason they would visit the website of the advertiser.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. And what about making a request in the background?

Comment: For example a browser extension could display a blank cover on ads and get the link on the ad. Then it makes in the background a request to the ad sometimes. But it would break the EULA I assume.

Comment: yes, you can't "secretly" visit a website in the background.  The user would have to open the page manually.  Advertisers devise systems so they can be sure a person visited the page by clicking on the specific ad and not by some other means.

Comment: How can they ensure so?

Comment: they prevent the load of pages inside iframes with php.  The ads also have auto-generated links that are unique.  every new ad has a different link that is saved by their server. if the server receives a request from that specific link, they know the ad was fully loaded, and that a user clicked on the link.  since ads are loaded in iframes, external javascript like adblock cannot have access to that link.